# Trigger API the end of ADF - CSV to Mongo migration

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a setup where Azure Data Factory converts a CSV into a MongoDB collection. I mean the entries of the CSV file are saved as records in Mongo DB. At the end of migration, I want to trigger an API (either microservice of Azure function) at the end of migration. Is it feasible to detect the end of migration to trigger the API? If yes, how to set up that in ADF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it feasible to detect the end of migration to trigger the API? If yes, how to set up that in ADF?

Yes, you can trigger the API After the successful end of migration with the help of Execute pipeline activity. you can call API or azure function from web activity or Azure function activity.

- First create pipeline which can migrate the entries of the CSV file are saved as records in Mongo DB.
  [image]
- Then create another pipeline with execute pipeline activity and web activity or Azure function activity. To ensure that the perform pipeline action runs in order rather than in parallel, make sure to select the `Wait on Completion` option.
  [image]
- Now run this pipeline it will run first pipeline after successful completion of it will trigger web activity or azure function activity.